# break *main VS break main() in GDB

Tags: gdb, breakpoints, watchpoint

what is the difference between `break *main` and `break main()` in essence?
for example:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int x=30;
        int y=40;
        x=y;
        return 0;
   }
```

when I use  `break *main` and `watch x`, it is this:

```
(gdb) b *main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400674: file aa.cpp, line 4.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /root/dd/aa.out 
Breakpoint 1, main () at aa.cpp:4
4       {
(gdb) n
5               int x=30;
(gdb) watch x
Hardware watchpoint 2: x
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hardware watchpoint 2: x

Old value = 0
New value = 30
main () at aa.cpp:6
6               int y=40;
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hardware watchpoint 2: x

Old value = 30
New value = 40
main () at aa.cpp:8
8               return 0;
(gdb)
```

but when I use `break main()` and `watch x`, it is this:

```
(gdb) b main()
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400678: file aa.cpp, line 5.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /root/dd/aa.out 
Breakpoint 1, main () at aa.cpp:5
5               int x=30;
(gdb) watch x
Hardware watchpoint 2: x
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hardware watchpoint 2: x

Old value = 0
New value = 40
main () at aa.cpp:8
8               return 0;
(gdb)
```

why are they different? And what is the difference in essence?

And when I watch an array, if I use `break main()`, it will appear:

```
Watchpoint 2 deleted because the program has left the block in
which its expression is valid.
```

but if I use `break *main`, it will not appear, why?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce with `gdb 7.12` and `g++ 6.2.1`, is suspect this might be version dependent. Could you post the versions you used as well as the compilation options you used?

Comment: my gdb version is 6.6, g++  4.1.2 and optimizion is -O0(g++ -g -o aa.out aa.cpp)  @FrederikDeweerdt

Answer (score 11):

> And what is the difference in essence

The difference is that `b *main` breaks on the first instruction of `main`, while `b main` breaks on the first instruction *after the [function prologue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue)*.

In my build (`g++ -g t.cc`, using `gcc 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3` and `gdb 7.9`), disassembly of your source looks like this:

```
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main():
   0x00000000004006cd <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x00000000004006ce <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00000000004006d1 <+4>: movl   $0x1e,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x00000000004006d8 <+11>:    movl   $0x28,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x00000000004006df <+18>:    mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
   0x00000000004006e2 <+21>:    mov    %eax,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x00000000004006e5 <+24>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x00000000004006ea <+29>:    pop    %rbp
   0x00000000004006eb <+30>:    retq
End of assembler dump.
```

And setting `b *main` vs. `b main` produces:

```
(gdb) b *main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4006cd: file t.c, line 4.
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 2 at 0x4006d1: file t.c, line 5.
```

I can not reproduce the problem you observed:

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Breakpoint 1, main () at t.c:4
4       {
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, main () at t.c:5
5           int x=30;
(gdb) p x
$1 = 0
(gdb) watch x
Hardware watchpoint 3: x
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hardware watchpoint 3: x

Old value = 0
New value = 30
main () at t.c:6
6           int y=40;
```

Comment: "The difference is that b *main breaks on the first instruction of main, while b main breaks on the first instruction after function prolog."  Does it mean they are almost the same?  @Employed Russian

Comment: @李鹏程 Yes, they are almost, but not exactly the same. The difference is precisely as described. I don't understand the point of your comment.

Comment: This answer was very helpful (as usual "Employed Russian"!).  I never knew about `*` prefix.

`help break` says: `Address locations begin with "*" and specify an exact address in the program.  Example: To specify the fourth byte past the start function "main", use "*main + 4".`