# difference between b main and b *main / find main return address in C

Tags: gdb

1. What is the difference between `b main` and `b *main` in gdb?
2. I want to find `main` return address using gdb.

Is it right?

```
(gdb) b main
(gdb) r
(gdb) x/x $esp
```

Comment: For 1) see http://stackoverflow.com/q/40960758/72178.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it right?

No.

This would be correct if you used `b *main` (on 32-bit `i*86` host), but not if you use `b main`.

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40962367/50617) explains, the former sets a breakpoint in the first instruction of `main` (when the stack pointer still points just below the return address pushed by the `CALL` instruction), the latter on the first instruction *after* function prolog (at which point several other values have likely been pushed onto the stack).