# Using '*' prior to addresses at gdb instructions "x" and "b"

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

In GDB, what is the difference between `b main` and `b *main`?

Similarly, is there any difference between `x/10i main` and `x/10i *main`? (10i is just an arbitrary example). What is the purpose of `*` prior to addresses?

Comment: i believe u can find some solution here :https://stackoverflow.com/a/40962367/14436359

Comment: Still, the "x" instruction produces the same result, with or without ``*`` (at least at an example I tried myself)

Answer (score 0):

For the `break` command, the difference is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40962367/50617).

For the `examine` command, there is no difference.